# Wordpress Permalink Redirection using RegExp

Tags: wordpress

I was using the following permalink structure on my wordpress blog previously

`http://domain.com/some-text-missing.html`

Now I have changed the permalink to

`http://domain.com/archives/2010/09/some-text-missing/`

The tag structure is

`http://domain.com/archives/tag/sometag/`

I am using the wordpress redirection plugin and I am stuck with the regular expressions.

Comment: You mean you're adding the date and time into the URL? So what are you trying to do - write redirects for all the existing pages to insert archive and the different dates into the URLs? i.e. you just want a regexp that matches the whole of "some-text-missing"?

Comment: Actually I have changed the Permalink/URL structure of my wordpress blog and I added a word archives and year/date combination to my new permalink. I am using the Wordpress redirection plugin to redirect all my old URL's to the new one. 

Here is the link to the plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the plugin you are using, but if there are not to many sites, i would do the redirects directly in .htaccess like this:

```
Redirect 301 /some-text-missing.html /archives/2010/09/some-text-missing/
```

you can't use here a regex because the new url structure has a new variable: the year/month. so regex wont know where to redirect your users. I don't know about your plugin, but i would write it myself, I would read the file name "some-text-missing" then search for it in the database and if found redirect to the new url.

Comment: I can't use this method because there are around 300 URL's to be redirected